# HttpClientHandler throwing PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, httpclient

The following code throws "PlatformNotSupportedException" 'Operation is not supported on this platform"

It is a NET standard library (tried compiling against 1.4 and 2.0) that is referenced by a .NET 4.6.1 project that runs as a web app.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

Why does Tls12 throw this exception and what is a workaround?

Comment: try to set `Proxy = null`, found it here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12282

Comment: @JericCruz: He doesn't run .NET Core, he runs on .NET Framework 4.6.1. The property doesn't exist on .NET Framework's `HttpClientHandler` class. The `dotnet/corefx` repository is for the .NET Core Runtime obviously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that the `SslProtocols` property doesn't exist on .NET Framework, it only exists in .NET Core.

You can see that in the Docs for `HttpClientHandler`.

- [.NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-2.0)

In .NET Framework you have to set it via `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, i.e.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

To achieve that in your .NET Standard PCL you'll most-likely have to do cross-compile to netstandard-2.0 **and** net461 as I'm not sure it still exists in .NET Standard/.NET Core.

#### edit:

Alternatively, remove it from your PCL and set it globally in your .NET Framework application via the static property above.

Comment: Ok it seems this has explained something to me. I thought my main app was netcore however it is targeting 4.6.1 still as some packages are not compatible. So I made the wrong choice using a net standard library, I should continue to use the old 4.6 package until the main Web app compiles against netcore. By using the old non net core package I won't have this error.

Answer (score 8):

This property was supposed to be implemented with .NET 4.7.1 per [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.sslprotocols?view=netframework-4.7.1) and is actually implemented and working on [.NET 4.7.2.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/05/announcing-net-framework-4-7-2-early-access-build-3052/)